# Concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, python-2.x

I try to stock string in my database with python script. But but when running the code I have this error cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects.

How can i decode this string "Poste Si\xe8ge" to be stocked successfully

```
    insert="INSERT INTO blacklist VALUES(INET_ATON('"+ long2ip(row[0]) +"'),NOW(),'"+ check.country +"',4,' ','"+detect[0]+"','"+ispTarget[0]+"')"

detect[0]=Poste Si\xe8ge

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Help me plz

Comment: Please show what you are doing.

Comment: insert="INSERT INTO blacklist VALUES(INET_ATON('"+ long2ip(row[0]) +"'),NOW(),'"+ check.country +"',4,' ','"+detect[0]+"','"+ispTarget[0]+"')"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: The problem seems not to be in the decode part. You are doing a concatenation (probably with a `+`) with a string and something you believe is a string but is actually not set. Can you provide more code to help you

Comment: At least one of your variable is not defined, can you check the value of `check.country`, `detect[0]` and `ispTarget[0]`

Comment: Please don't build up SQL from string concatenation when you could use a parameterised query instead.

Comment: the problem is solved, thnx @Jaay

Answer (score 20):

Did you try `str()` in-built function.?

If you concatenate string objects with other data types, then the other type has to be converted to `str(other_data_type)`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This will *suppress* the error, but almost certainly won't fix the bug which is usually caused by some variable not having the expected (string) value.

Comment: Note that "str(None)" returns "None", rather than an empty string.

Answer (score 10):

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

This error actually describes very well what is happening: You are trying to concatenate a string with something else which happens to be `None`. For example:

```
>>> 'foo' + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    'foo' + None
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Of course, you probably don’t try to concatenate `None` explicitely but you have some variable instead, e.g. `'foo' + bar`. Now this means that `bar` is actually `None`, so the concatenation fails.

In your case, you are concatenating the values `long2ip(row[0])`, `check.country`, `detect[0]`, and `ispTarget[0]` with the string. So at least one of those is `None`. So check these values and make sure that none of them is `None` (for example make sure `long2ip` actually *returns* a value). And then it should work fine.